# how do I stop mysql running on my server? Standard solutions not working

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I have done a remote log-in into my `Ubuntu 14.04` server as a root user.

When I try:

```
sudo stop mysql
```

I get:

```
stop: unknown instance:
```

When I try:

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

I get:

```
stop: unknown instance:
```

I read a post somewhere where someone posted a similar question, the answer being that the server is most likely already not running so I tried:

```
mysqladmin -u root -p status
```

And I get `Uptime: 1543 Threads: 1 Questions: 500 etc...`

...which means the server is indeed running.

So, how do I stop `mysql`? I'm sure I tried `sudo stop mysql` before and it worked.

Today I added a password for access to the mysql db as a root user, could that be something to do with it?

I know the password is working ok because I need to enter it in order to log into `phpMyAdmin`.

With `service mysql status` I get `mysql stop/waiting` like it's hanging - shouldn't it just shut down eventually?

Answer (score 2):

Stop MySQL: `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop`

Stop Apache: `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop`

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo systemctl status mysqld` then, if successful, `sudo systemctl stop mysqld`.

The name of the service may be different (officially is `mysqld`).

Comment: With that I get sudo: systemctl: command not found

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu is? Try `sudo service mysqld stop`.

Comment: It is Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the command 'Service'.

sudo service mysql stop

Comment: Thanks but I already tried that one, as indicated in question. With 'service mysql status' I get 'mysql stop/waiting' like it's hanging or something, looks weird to me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it eventually.

I looked up the Process ID (PID) for `mysqld_safe` using:

```
ps -A
```

This will show all the `PIDs` currently running on the server.

`mysqld_safe` was something like `34567`

Then I did the command: `kill -KILL 34567`

Also, I killed the `PID` of `mysqld`, which was something like `34678`:

```
kill -KILL 34678
```

Then I did `service mysql start`

All working good now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with sudo service mysql stop is that systemctl will restart the service after a few minutes.  You need to stop it with systemctl.

Comment: You're saying that if you stop a service, it restarts itself? What?